# Subquery returned more than 1 value using XML cast

Tags: sql, xml, select, declare

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE list_select (@id INT)

AS

IF (@id IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml XML = CAST((SELECT data FROM messages WHERE id = @id) AS XML)
    DECLARE @reference VARCHAR(MAX) =  @xml.value('(/*:xml/*:reference/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(MAX) = @xml.value('(/*:xml/*:name/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')

END

SELECT
    @reference as reference,
    @name as name
GO
```

How can i get this to work with more than one value?

Comment: Within your table `messages` there seems to be a column `data`. What is the datatype of this column and what is the content looking like? Is the column `id` unique within this table? MIght be you are trying to get an XML of several rows out of `messages`... Very unclear... I'm pretty sure, that this can be done better. Probably with an *inline TVF* or a `VIEW`.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* `for xml path` does what you want:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = (SELECT data FROM messages WHERE id = @id FOR XML PATH (''))
```